# Jupyter Notebook kernel keep crashing(Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am running a tensorflow code but the kernel of jupyter notebook keeps crashing, i searched the error i was getting in logs which said "Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193". I tried the solutions from differenct users of using compatible CUDA and cuDnn. Tried various combinations but the error still remains same.
Versions of CUDA and cuDnn I tried are:
Cuda v11.7 cudnn 8.4.0.27
Cuda v11.6 cudnn 8.4.0.27
Cuda v11.6 cudnn 8.3.1.22

I have also given the paths of Cuda and cudnn correctly in the environment variable.

Here is the logs...

```
C:\Users\Sachal Raja>jupyter-notebook
[I 17:18:55.635 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Sachal Raja
[I 17:18:55.635 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.11 is running at:
[I 17:18:55.635 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=ea2a961618582e46f95937ee7beee00c8cd163dfc3230502
[I 17:18:55.635 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ea2a961618582e46f95937ee7beee00c8cd163dfc3230502
[I 17:18:55.635 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 17:18:55.870 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Sachal%20Raja/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13152-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=ea2a961618582e46f95937ee7beee00c8cd163dfc3230502
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ea2a961618582e46f95937ee7beee00c8cd163dfc3230502
[W 17:19:15.744 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20220521171854 (::1) 64.830000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/ctc_asr.ipynb
[I 17:19:17.391 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 49107dc3-9e85-4e51-b176-37b4c2881f4f, name: python3
2022-05-21 17:19:44.730767: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-05-21 17:19:51.600339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 2149 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-05-21 17:19:51.662909: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2149 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-05-21 17:20:30.323369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8400
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193
[I 17:20:32.374 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel 49107dc3-9e85-4e51-b176-37b4c2881f4f restarted
```

Code snippet where error arises:
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSlHh.png)

Comment: Do you have a NVIDIA GPU card on your machine?  Are you sure it's a supported version?  Are you using Anaconda to set up the environment for your Jupyter notebook?    Have you tried dropping back to CPU only and see if that works?  Solve the problem in steps.  I'm running locally on a Mac M1 with Anaconda.

Comment: @Sachal Kindly check the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and install the compatible versions of CUDA and cuDNN and let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!